# Why doesn't my batch file work in Windows CE?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-ce

My script is not executing on Windows CE version 8.

I am getting a file path from the user as input, appending the filename and attempting to 'start' it.

But the `@ echo off` isn't considered and all commands are shown in the console when runing in the device. Also, none of the start commands nor the `set /p` command is run. Error is shown

```
@ echo off
if exist clientshutdown3.exe (
   start clientshutdown3.exe
   start ConmanClient3.exe
   start CMAccept3.exe
   start MSVSMON.EXE
 ) else (
   set /p mypath=Enter path of pdf file: 
)

if defined mypath start "" "%mypath%\clientshutdown3.exe" 
if defined mypath start "" "%mypath%\ConmanClient3.exe" 
if defined mypath start "" "%mypath%\CMAccept3.exe" 
if defined mypath start "" "%mypath%\MSVSMON.EXE"
```

Comment: Which error is shown?

Comment: can you test something simple? create a new file and do. `set /p "mypath=Enter path of pdf file: " && call echo %mypath% && pause` also, are you still running the same cmd window you did before the changes in your previous question? Remeber that one broke the environment.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I'm using your code only, with the variable name set to mypath. When execiting set /p, it isn't waiting for user input.

Comment: then maybe `set` does not allow the `/p` switch? can you manually run `set /?` from cmdline and see if it has any `/p` switch in the help?

Comment: `set /p` and `if defined` are Windows NT's cmd.exe features. Therefore they may not be available in WinCE. Try `echo %comspec%` to see what your shell is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wikipedia [the console in WinCE is also cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). However they're not the same cmd.exe, so their functionality will be different

From the list of [Command Processor Commands (Windows CE 5.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms907227?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on MSDN it seems Windows CE's cmd.exe is very primitive and more like command.com than Windows NT's cmd.exe. For example it [doesn't support `exit /B`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa453059) or [`copy /B`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms908150) and so on. Similarly it [**doesn't have `set /P`**, `set /A` or `set "with=quote"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms939984?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and supports only

```
SET [variable=[string]]
```

I've also found another detailed list of [Script Commands for Windows Mobile Devices](https://www.soti.net/mc/help/v14.2/en/scriptcmds/reference/windowsmobile.html). In this list the [`if` command](https://www.soti.net/mc/help/v14.2/en/scriptcmds/reference/if_cmd.html) is claimed to have only the below forms

```
if [not] errorlevel number scriptCommand 
if [not] string1==string2 command 
if [not] exist filename command 
if [not] procexists processName command
```

There's no `if defined` in this list. However the [document on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms929941) disagrees, as it doesn't list the strange `procexists` form but the `IF [NOT] DEFINED variable command` one

Nevertheless, both agree that **`if` can't have an `else`**, thus your if/else block won't work either. And even if it has `if defined`, the last lines in your script won't work because you used `start ""` which isn't available in WinCE. You must use [`START command [parameters]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms940348) instead

### In summary, you'll get issues with `if/else`, `set /P` and `start ""` (and possibly `if defined`)

Answer (score 2):

The Windows CE command shell is not nearly as powerful as it's NT brothers.
Set /P is not supported under CE.

The shell hasn't changed since v5. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_Compact)

Here are a list of the v5 supported commands and their parameters.
http://nellisks.com/ref/dos/ce/SET.html

You can easily code this behavior up using another language if you really need to solve this using the shell.

Good luck.